# Geodjango and Innodb, mixed innodb and myisam models

Tags: mysql, django, innodb, myisam, geodjango

I keep hearing that InnoDB is better for data integrity, unfortunately as of MySQL 5.6 it has yet to support SPATIAL indexes. A fast SPATIAL index is pretty critical to my app, though what's nice about my model that it's pretty much results in a fairly static (write once, read many) table of (ID, POINT), so I could use MyISAM and not care too much.

I'd like to restrict the use of MyISAM to just that table, and migrate it over when InnoDB support for SPATIAL is ready. Problem is, if I ALTER TABLE after my models are migrated (by having an app/sql/app_model.sql) to switch the table to MyISAM, MySQL complains:

```
ERROR 1217 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

That makes sense, my other models refer to this one and Django automatically makes FOREIGN KEY constraints between those models and this one.

What's the best strategy here? Should I abandon InnoDB and switch everything back to MyISAM? Can I just drop all the FOREIGN KEY constraints?

I tried automating the FOREIGN KEY drops by looking in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS, but that only lists the tables that have the constraints, not the tables referred to by those constraints. I would have to do some fuzzy column name matching which feels very brittle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I gave up on using InnoDB by default. Because Amazon RDS makes Inno the default, I did this by adding an init_command in my settings.py:

```
'default': {
    'OPTIONS': {
        'init_command' : 'SET storage_engine=MYISAM', # Can't make SPATIAL keys on InnoDB
    },
}
```

Then for all but the table with a SPATIAL index I created a $modelname.sql file under the $appname/sql directory that changes the engine after it's created.

```
-- Alter to InnoDB so we can make concurrent insertions w/o full table lock.
ALTER TABLE <modeltable> ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Switching to MYISAM default means Django doesn't automatically create the FOREIGN KEY constraints for you for your Inno tables which isn't ideal. I wish there was a way to make Django create them after-the-fact.